# Safari Absolute Positioning via Javascript

Tags: javascript, css-position, safari

I am creating a wheel selector for choosing cocktails based on mood. It uses an image map and when hovering over a particular area there is a hover state generated by javascript. It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and IE9, but I'm having issues with Safari. Absolute positioning does not seem to be applying to my hover indicator.

See it in action here:
http://thehoochlife.com/mood-selector-test/

Here is an example of the javascript I use to create the hover state on the image map's area:

```
function overStubborn() {
indicator.css({
    'display' : 'block',
    'left' : '227px',
    'top' : '54px',
    '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(169deg)',
    '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(169deg)',
    '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(169deg)',
    '-o-transform' : 'rotate(169deg)',
    'transform' : 'rotate(169deg)'
});
indicator.on('click', function() {
    jQuery('#stubborn').click();
    return false;
});
}
```

The CSS for the .indicator element is:

```
.mood-selector .indicator {
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
height: 27px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
}
```

There is a `position: absolute;` on `.mood-selector`.
Any ideas why the absolute positioning isn't working in Safari? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean with 'not working'? What does exactly happens? Please, explain yourself better

Comment: Works here. Are you sure there's a bug?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I'm experiencing the issue on my Mac, my coworkers Mac and in Windows, all in Safari. If you hover over a mood and move the cursor to an adjacent mood without leaving the wheel the .indicator rotates as specified in -webkit-transform, but does not move to the left and top coordinates specified in the JavaScript.

Comment: I decided to disable the hover states in Safari for the time being, but I've posted a new link in the question that still has the Safari bug in case anyone is able to help me figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Known issue with combine `absolute position` and `transform` together.

See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82225

I encountered same issue on Safari and worked on Chrome, and found out two solutions, you could take apart `indicator` into two element, parent for position and child for transforming, or you could add `translateZ(0)` in `transform`, i.e. `'-webkit-transform' : rotate(169deg) translateZ(0)`.